# Crystal reports don't run after changing to SqlServer 2014

Tags: jakarta-ee, crystal-reports, report

We design our reports using Crystal Reports Designer 11.x.

For our reports, we use JDBC/JNDI connection. We have been using the Java Runtime Component libraries of Crystal.Then when we open (run) the reports in our J2EE application, it runs the reports against the runtime JNDI accessible database, and brings results.
All the reports were working fine. Even now if I change my database connection to a SqlServer database earlier to 2014, they work great.
I developed a very simple report, to pull few columns from one table. It works great with SqlServer databases prior to version 2014, but fails with the following errors in version 2014:

```
2017-08-02 19:47:57,751 WARN  [JRCLicenseThrottler] Overriding keycode. Number of Concurrent Requests=5
2017-08-02 19:47:59,023 ERROR [ReportDocument] Error adding azalea functions from Library
com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaFunctionSetupException: The class com.azalea.ufl.BarcodeLibrary could not be instantiated as a FormulaFunctionLibrary.
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FunctionManager.createExternalFunctionLibrary(SourceFile:163)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.ReportDocument.a2(SourceFile:160)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.ReportDocument.<clinit>(SourceFile:119)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.DataSourceManager.<clinit>(SourceFile:129)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.DataSourceManagerFactory.a(SourceFile:37)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.reportconverter.v12.V12SaveLoader.a(SourceFile:236)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.loader.ReportLoader.a(SourceFile:205)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCReportLoader.a(SourceFile:137)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCReportLoader.a(SourceFile:76)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.requesthandler.ReportDocumentRequestHandler.a(SourceFile:137)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.<init>(SourceFile:228)
    at com.businessobjects.sdk.erom.jrc.a.<init>(SourceFile:43)
    at com.businessobjects.sdk.erom.jrc.ReportAgentFactory.createAgent(SourceFile:46)
    at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.RemoteAgent$a.<init>(SourceFile:703)
    at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.RemoteAgent.a(SourceFile:662)
    at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.RemoteAgent.a(SourceFile:632)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ClientDocument.if(SourceFile:504)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ClientDocument.open(SourceFile:669)
    at com.sa.v4.web.display.CustomReportsBean.readReportParameter(CustomReportsBean.java:295)
    at com.sa.v4.web.display.CustomReportsBean.processMloReportParameter(CustomReportsBean.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sa.v4.web.renewal.BeanAction.execute(BeanAction.java:233)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-08-02 19:47:59,315 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:47:59,322 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:47:59,323 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:47:59,324 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:47:59,324 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:47:59,324 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:47:59,325 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:47:59,325 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:47:59,326 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:47:59,326 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:47:59,717 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:47:59,717 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:47:59,717 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:47:59,718 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:47:59,718 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:47:59,719 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:47:59,719 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:47:59,719 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:47:59,720 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:47:59,720 WARN  [V12Converter] UNSUPPORTED: Section property not supported: isInReadOnlyArea
2017-08-02 19:48:00,214 ERROR [JRCCommunicationAdapter]  detected an exception: Unexpected database connector error
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.datafoundation.DFQuery.for(SourceFile:632)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.datalayer.a.do(SourceFile:1621)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.datalayer.a.a(SourceFile:1404)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.m.b(SourceFile:334)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.j.b(SourceFile:515)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.m.o(SourceFile:408)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.m.a(SourceFile:173)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.ContextNode.a(SourceFile:114)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.ContextNode.a(SourceFile:95)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.j.case(SourceFile:1080)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.h.<init>(SourceFile:108)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.DataContext.a(SourceFile:254)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.DataProcessor2.a(SourceFile:4660)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.DataProcessor2.a(SourceFile:4574)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.DataProcessor2.new(SourceFile:2652)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.DataProcessor2.byte(SourceFile:2610)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.DataProcessor2.try(SourceFile:2282)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.DataProcessor2.int(SourceFile:2442)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.DataProcessor2.I(SourceFile:1013)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.objectformatter.ObjectFormatter.fp(SourceFile:526)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.paginator.PageFormatter.if(SourceFile:613)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.paginator.PageFormatter.a(SourceFile:578)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.paginator.PageFormatter.X(SourceFile:387)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.paginator.PageFormatter.moveToPageN(SourceFile:339)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.requesthandler.ReportViewingRequestHandler.a(SourceFile:1091)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.requesthandler.ReportViewingRequestHandler.byte(SourceFile:218)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.do(SourceFile:1908)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.if(SourceFile:660)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.a(SourceFile:166)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter$2.a(SourceFile:528)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter$2.call(SourceFile:526)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.ThreadGuard.syncExecute(SourceFile:102)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.for(SourceFile:524)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.int(SourceFile:423)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.request(SourceFile:351)
    at com.businessobjects.sdk.erom.jrc.a.a(SourceFile:54)
    at com.businessobjects.sdk.erom.jrc.a.execute(SourceFile:67)
    at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.RemoteAgent$a.execute(SourceFile:716)
    at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.CommunicationChannel.a(SourceFile:125)
    at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.RemoteAgent.a(SourceFile:537)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ds.a(SourceFile:186)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportSource.a(SourceFile:1558)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportSource.getPage(SourceFile:767)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.AdvancedReportSource.getPage(SourceFile:324)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportengineinterface.JPEReportSource.getPage(SourceFile:149)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.event.s.a(SourceFile:158)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.event.s.a(SourceFile:127)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.event.bt.a(SourceFile:47)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.event.bw.broadcast(SourceFile:93)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.event.am.a(SourceFile:53)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.a.t.if(SourceFile:2104)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.e.a(SourceFile:300)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.e.a(SourceFile:202)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.e.a(SourceFile:135)
    at com.crystaldecisions.report.web.ServerControl.a(SourceFile:607)
    at com.crystaldecisions.report.web.ServerControl.processHttpRequest(SourceFile:342)
    at org.apache.jsp.viewCustomReport_jsp._jspService(viewCustomReport_jsp.java:172)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I have experienced that the JRC component spitting this "database connector error" for a variety of reasons. Since the report works with earlier SqlServer versions, this does not seem to be a great help. However, we have another prior error:
**FormulaFunctionSetupException: The class com.azalea.ufl.BarcodeLibrary could not be instantiated** ...First thing to note is, I do not have any formulas or functions in my report. Then why, that too only for SqlServer 2014 database, the [com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FunctionManager] is trying to go for some formula library?
This is puzzling!

Comment: May be the formula library related error can be ignored. I mean it may not be related to the next exception/error: **[JRCCommunicationAdapter]  detected an exception: Unexpected database connector error**. If anyone knows anything related to this, please let me know.